# Remove item from list of associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a list of associative arrays:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'john',
        'foo' => 'fee'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'peter',
        'foo' => 'fi'
    )
);
```

and I want to remove (unset) foo from each array in the list. I have the following code to do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    unset($arr[$i]['foo']);
```

As I potentially have several hundred arrays in this list, **I'm wondering if this is the most efficient method.** I took a look through the list of array functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) but nothing struck me as a relevant alternative.

Comment: What makes you think this is not efficient? )

Comment: most efficient method is don't remove them, or even don't set them...

Comment: because i'm looping through the first list. there may be a more efficient method of searching for the keys in the 2nd level of arrays.

Comment: you want to know if there's a more efficient method of searching for the key in the 2nd level array than just straight unsetting it without searching for it first like you are already doing?

Comment: @vp_arth the data is needed in the first instance, but then it needs to be passed on to somewhere else x-network, so i want to reduce the size of the data for futrue efficiency.

Comment: @CrayonViolent exactly.

Comment: Compare it with `array_map(function($a){unset($a['foo'])}, $arr);` :)

Comment: thx @vp_arth can u recommend any tools for comparing?

Comment: I suggest `microtime` tool. It integrated to your PHP build

Comment: @dewd I don't think you can get any more "efficient" than just assuming it's there and unsetting it, because what you are currently doing *isn't actually searching for it, it's just assuming it's there and unsetting it*.

Comment: thx @CrayonViolent. i'll give this method vs the array_map method a comparison and post the results.

Comment: It is `foreach Vs array_map holy war` They almost exact... microoptimizations, but array_map likes me more)

Comment: ok @vp_arth. it's always good to know you're following best practice, rather just coding for getting the job done, no matter what the performance implications.

Comment: well legibility and scalability trumps performance/efficiency in "best practice" arena. If efficiency were most important, OOP wouldn't be a thing

Comment: It would be more efficient to not have the array to start with. This is what databases are for.

Comment: @CrayonViolent you're right. i'm a converted OOP, having been functional most of programming career. it's easy to slow things up with OOP if you get it wrong.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, if performance is so important, sometimes php wouldn't be a thing))

Comment: @JBES at some point you've got to get the data out of the db and do something with it! holding it in memory has got to be much quicker than numerous db calls for the same data?! or not??

Comment: @vp_arth my statement applies to *any* language that uses OOP. OOP adds extra layers of code that is completely unnecessary for the computer to do its job. OOP principles, designs and practices are there for many wonderful reasons, but efficiency isn't one of them

Comment: @dewd well since you haven't given us the bigger picture, all we see is that you have a multi-dim array with a key/value you want to get rid of, and it sounds like you have the power to make it not be there in the first place. So without the bigger picture, as far as we are concerned, the *right* answer is to have it not be popped in your multi-dim array in the first place. But even on your response to that.. where is this array going after that? is having it in there going to break it? because again, the more efficient thing would be to leave it there and have the next bit of code ignore it

Comment: @CrayonViolent, often it's impossible to support large projects without any structure... Yes, OOP can be heavy, but also it can be beauty...

Comment: @vp_arth I completely agree, no argument there. But the theme here is efficiency, and I got the impression that OP thought efficiency==best practice, so I was using OOP as an example of how that isn't true.

Comment: @CrayonViolent the key/value in the multi-dim is required. like you say, if it wasn't i wouldn't have it there. but the multi-dim goes on to do other things x-network where the specific key/value isn't required. options: 1) efficient key/ value removal 2) leave it there and take network/ memory hit, 3) 2 seperate queries from db. i think 1 is best. thx for your help. it's appreciated.

Comment: @vp_arth for some reason, your array_map unsets the whole array, not just the key/value being targeted? i'm looking into it. `$arr = array_map(function($a){unset($a['foo']);}, $arr);`

Comment: @dewd, my bad, sorry) Try `array_walk($arr, function($a){unset($a['foo']);});` without any other assignments... ps: I love php for it's standarts, arguments order, for example)))

Comment: @dewd, use a loop) unset isn't work on a outer array)) sorry

Comment: @dewd, only this way worked: `array_walk($arr, function($a, $k)use(&$arr){unset($arr[$k]['foo']);});`

Comment: `array_walk` comes out 10x slower than the loop, so i guess that settles it! thx all.

Comment: @dewd - Yes, but not all at once. It's slow and cumbersome, as you are finding out. If your data is in a database, modify it there - which it probably isn't as you specify you have a list in an array. You also don't need numerous calls within the database. One will remove the entire column "foo" within milliseconds.

Comment: @JBES the extra value i need initially and then throw away is 1 column in 1 query returning several rows (1st array) and several columns (2nd associative array). i need the results together initially, and then need to/should drop one column. thx for your advice in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the other options to my question might include `array_map` or `array_walk`. On an array of 150 items of associative arrays, **the for loop came out ~10x quicker than the `array_walk` function**. the `array_map` function didn't work on a multi-dimensional array. the avg times were as follows (3 goes each):

for loop: 0.000136
array_walk: 0.001452

thx everyone for the help and debate on this topic.